# how to draw a triangle with PIL?

Tags: image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

i am trying to draw a triangle with PIL ImageDraw
this is the code that i have

```
    t1 = int(tri[0])
    t2 = int(tri[1])
    t3 = int(tri[2])
    t4 = int(tri[3])
    t5 = int(tri[4])
    t6 = int(tri[5])
    t7 = int(tri[6])
    t8 = int(tri[7])
    t9 = int(tri[8])
    t10 = int(tri[9])
    draw.polygon((t1,t2),(t3,t4),(t5,t6), fill=(t7,t8,t9,t10))
```

i am getting the error

> TypeError: polygon() got multiple values for argument 'fill'

is there any way that i can make a triangle without getting this error

python 2.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw

# Create empty black canvas
im = Image.new('RGB', (255, 255))

# Draw red and yellow triangles on it and save
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon([(20,10), (200, 200), (100,20)], fill = (255,0,0))
draw.polygon([(200,10), (200, 200), (150,50)], fill = 'yellow')

im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked  i was just missing a set of square brackets for the coordinates

Comment: Note that if the points are stored in a numpy array, you need to convert it to a list: `draw.polygon(points.flatten().tolist(), fill=(255, 0, 0))`. Otherwise it will not draw anything, and it does not even raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

`draw.polygon(((t1,t2),(t3,t4),(t5,t6)), fill=(t7,t8,t9,t10))`

instead of

`draw.polygon((t1,t2),(t3,t4),(t5,t6), fill=(t7,t8,t9,t10))`

brackets missing